# Differential orbits(?)

Tags: geometry

Two circles rotating counter clock wise. 
Draw a line between the centers and place a dot on the surface of each 
where the line crosses. 
Circle one. radius 6378 Km rotating at 3 Km/sec.
Circle 2 radius 696343 Km Rotating at 48.2 Km sec.

What length of time will it take for the two dots to line up again?

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be the line segment between two centers. Also, let $A,B$ be the intersection point of $L$ and circle $1,2$ respectively.

Letting $O_1$ be the center of circle $1$, the dot on circle $1$ comes on the line $AO_1$ after
$$\frac{2\pi a}{3}t$$
seconds where $a$ is the radius of circle $1$ and $t\ge 1\in\mathbb N$.

The same argument above tells us that the dot on circle $2$ comes on the line $BO_2$ after
$$\frac{2\pi b}{48.2}u$$
seconds where $b$ is the radius of circle $1$ and $u\ge 1\in\mathbb N$.

Now, we know that we have the following equation :

$$\frac{2\pi a}{3}t=\frac{2\pi b}{48.2}u.$$

Simplifying this gives us
$$5\times 696343u=2\times 241\times 1063t.$$
Noting that each of $5, 696343, 2,241, 1063$ is a prime number, we have
$$u=2\times 241\times 1063\times k,$$
$$t=5\times 696343\times l$$
where $k,l\ge 1\in\mathbb N.$

Now, what we want is the least common multiple of $t,u$, so the answer will be
$$2\times 5\times 241\times 1063\times 696343\ \text{(seconds)}\approx 56567\ \text{(years)}.$$

Comment: @robert : Doesn't my answer help?

Comment: I wanted to thank you for this masterpiece of fine craftsmanship. I had the initial formula 2pia/3*t=2pib/48.2 *u in mind as distance1=distance2 if rate1*time2 = rate2*time1.

Comment: @robert: You are welcome. Yes, you are right. I hope my answer helps.